# ag-grid side bar comming by default to all ag-grids present in application

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I set ag-grid licence in `main.ts` file. So by default sidebar comes with Column tab to all ag-grid present in application. It's not allowing me to use `[sideBar]="true"` or `[sideBar]="false"`.

I expect there is the way to disable it.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Post your html/ts related to the declaration of the ag-grid.

Comment: <ag-grid-angular 
    class="ag-theme-balham fbackactive" 
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
    enableColResize 
    enableSorting 
    enableFilter 
    [floatingFilter]="true"
    [colResizeDefault]="colResizeDefault"
    (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)" 
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)">
 </ag-grid-angular>

Comment: now i have not added side bar related code in html file then also m getting side bar

Comment: Edit your question and add code there next time. So what happens when you try to add `[sideBar]="true/false"`?

Comment: as show in my code i didnt mention [sideBar]="true/false" then also am getting side bar.

Answer (score 0):

**If you [don't need](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#configuring-the-side-bar) the `sideBar` just don't define it**

> `undefined`    No side bar provided.

[**Boolean Configuration**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#boolean-configuration)

> *The default side bar contains the Columns and Filters tool panels. To use the default side bar, set the grid property `sideBar=true`. The Columns panel will be open by default*
>
> **The default configuration doesn't allow customisation of the tool panels. More detailed configurations are explained below.**
>
> In the following example note the following:
>
> 1. The grid property `sideBar` is set to `true`.
> 2. The side bar is displayed with tool panels `Columns` and `Filters`.
> 3. The `Columns` panel is displayed by **default**.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FuLToB4DOwqhcRZD)</kbd>

Comment: Just i set enterprise licence key then the side bar coming by default to all pages of ag-grid in apllication. i didnt use [sideBar]="true/false" then also side bar is coming.

Comment: check demo button, and what version of ag-grid you are using?